# How to recover auto committed transaction in Oracle with normal privilage

Tags: oracle, rollback

I have updated the table & need to rollback that changes.

1. I have tried Rollback work command but data still not rollback.
2. I have also tried Flashback command but it is not working because "row movement is not enabled"

Could you please help me out. I don't have DBA access as well, still I need to recover the data.

Comment: Could you provide a piece of your code as a example?

Comment: Talk with the DBA.  Normal users aren't likely to be able to reverse a committed transaction.  I'm not sure which "flashback command" you used-- there are lots of different commands in that family of technologies that do very different things under the covers.  If you are lucky and the old data is still in `UNDO`, you may be able to run a flashback query and use the results of that query to update the data to the old values.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recover the committed transaction with a normal privilege.
However, you may be able to 
ask your DBA to flashback(If the database is set up with flashback enabled for tables and `UNDO_RETENTION` has set approximately)the table to a specific point in time, or,assumin they are using hot backups, [Database Point-In Time Recovery](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/rcmflash.htm#i1011846)(This option will also rollback changes made by others on the database) could be an alternative for flashback.

For details:[Rewinding a Table with Flashback Table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/rcmflash.htm#BRADV81517)

Comment: on the table in SQL Developer, look at the FLASHBACK page. you might be able to see your change there, and below you will see the UNDO SQL to make it...go back